# Forcing an object that subscribed to events to be destroyed

Tags: f#

let's look at the following code:

```
type EventSource () =

    let myEvent = Event<DateTime>()

    do
        let timer = new Timers.Timer()
        timer.Elapsed.Add (fun _ -> myEvent.Trigger DateTime.UtcNow)
        timer.Interval <- TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.).TotalMilliseconds
        timer.Enabled <- true
        timer.Start()

    member this.OnEvent() =
        myEvent.Publish


type DoStuff (eventSource: EventSource) =

    // sometimes this object will self terminate its activity
    do
        eventSource.OnEvent().Add(fun t -> printfn "I got the time: %A" t)




type DoStuffController () =

    let mutable activeObject : DoStuff option = None

    let eventSource = EventSource()

    member this.Start () =
        activeObject <- Some (DoStuff(eventSource))


    member this.Stop () =
        -> destroy active object here
        activeObject <- None
```

This is a simplified version of a problem I have:
There is a module that generates events.
Then there is a controller that will create objects on demand (one available at a time) and these objects will subscribe to the events.
These objects (DoStuff) can self destruct, or can be destructed on demand.

Since the object has subscribed to an event, it will not go out of scope if I remove any reference to the object.

What would be a good way to force the destruction?
since the object can decide to finish its activity on its own, I was thinking to add a method that triggers the self destruction, so it is done from a single point.
Is there any elegant way to do this?

It is used in a context where an external command comes to start / stop a process; there can be only one at a time (they're different, just using the same base abstract class).
Part of the operation requires to subscribe to events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IDisposables:

```ml
type DoStuff (eventSource: EventSource) =
    let disp =
        eventSource.OnEvent()
        |> Observable.subscribe(printfn "I got the time: %A")
    interface IDisposable with member t.Dispose() = disp.Dispose()

type DoStuffController () =
    let mutable activeObject : DoStuff option = None
    let eventSource = EventSource()
    let clear() =
        activeObject |> Option.iter (fun ds -> (ds:>IDisposable).Dispose())
    member this.Start () =
        clear()
        activeObject <- Some (new DoStuff(eventSource))
    member this.Stop () =
        clear()
        activeObject <- None
```

Comment: is Observable similar to Event in the sense that one callback has to be finished for the next one to go through? or can multiple events trigger multiple callbacks at the same time (necessitating a lock)

Comment: I have never used Observable, but I believe the behavior will let multiple events to be used concurrently.

Comment: I just did some test and this is the case. Additionally, a lock will not help because after the object is disposed, events queued behind the lock will still execute